# R: Exact p-values Wilcoxon Matched Pairs Test with Ties

Tags: r, p-value, pairwise.wilcox.test

How can exact p-values be obtained for this test when there are ties? Wilcox.test returns warnings when this happens as shown:

```
1: In wilcox.test.default(x = c3a0, y = c3a1, alternative = c("two.sided",  :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
2: In wilcox.test.default(x = c3a0, y = c3a1, alternative = c("two.sided",  :
  cannot compute exact confidence interval with ties
```

Comment: The help file for `wilcox.test` appears to answer this for you under _See also_: _"`wilcox_test` in package `coin` for exact, asymptotic and Monte Carlo conditional p-values, including in the presence of ties."_

Comment: You cannot. See for one example https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/514618/ties-in-wilcoxon-t-test-in-r. There are bootstrapping/Monte Carlo approaches, but you won't get an exact value.

Comment: I should have added, this is probably more of a stats question than an R question. You might ask over there but check earlier posts first. This is likely overasked.

Answer (score 0):

The coin::wilcoxsign_test() method handles ties using two options: Wilcoxon and Pratt. Let me quote the documentation ("zeros" refer to the ties):

> For wilcoxsign_test,  the  default  method  of  handling  zeros
> (zero.method = "Pratt"),  due  to Pratt (1959), first rank-transforms
> the absolute differences (including zeros) and then discards the ranks
> corresponding to the zero-differences.  The proposal by Wilcoxon
> (1949, p.  6) first discards the zero-differences and then
> rank-transforms the remaining absolute differences (zero.method
> ="Wilcoxon").
>
> Starting with coin version 1.0-16, the zero.method argument replaced
> the (now removed) ties.method argument. The current default is
> zero.method = "Pratt" whereas earlier versions had ties.method=
> "HollanderWolfe", which is equivalent to zero.method = "Wilcoxon"

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coin/coin.pdf